# HelloSign API - getting "This SignatureRequest will be placed on hold until the user confirms their email address"

Tags: api, curl, electronic-signature

"When using the HelloSign API I'm getting ""This SignatureRequest will be placed on hold until the user confirms their email address"" when I send a signature request as part of the response:

""warnings"":[{""warning_msg"":""This SignatureRequest will be placed on hold until the user confirms their email address."",""warning_name"":""unconfirmed""}

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

My request looks like this:

curl -u ""[my api key]:"" 'https://api.hellosign.com/v3/signature_request/send' -F ""file[0]=@doc.pdf"" -F 'title=One Signer' -F 'message=Please sign this document.' -F 'signers[1][email_address]=person@example.com' -F 'signers[1][name]=John Doe' -F 'test_mode=1'"

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the account you're using to send the request is not confirmed (i.e., you haven't activated your account using the email HelloSign sent you). Check your email for an activation link, or attempt to sign into the HelloSign website and send a signature request there. I believe that will send you another activation email.

HelloSign does this as a way of verifying you actually own that email address. This is how they are able to comply with eSignature laws with respect to identifying a user by an email address.